# Efficient variadic equals-any function

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, variadic-templates

I want to make a function that returns whether the first parameter equals any of the others. This is what I came up with:

```
template<typename T, typename... U>
bool equalsAny(T first, U... args) {
    U arr[] {args...};
    for (auto& arg : arr) if (first == arg) return true;
    return false;
}
```

This is of course very slow in the sense that an array must be created for all arguments. Is there any way to make this almost as fast as `first == arg1 || first == arg2 || ...` by for instance using c++17 fold expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tagged C++17 so... what's wrong with template folding ?

```
template <typename T, typename... U>
bool equalsAny (T first, U... args)
 { return (first == args || ...); }
```

Pre C++17, you can use the initialization of an unused C-style array (I'm not an expert but I suppose that a good compiler can optimize it very well)

```
template <typename T, typename... U>
bool equalsAny (T first, U... args)
 { 
   using unused = bool[];

   bool ret { false };

   (void)unused { false, (ret = ret || (first == args))... };

   return ret;
}
```